# Libc++ linked programs fail with symbol lookup error

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, clang, libc++

I've recently built libc++ from scratch as my prject needs some features that are not yet implemnted in libstdc++.

I try to compile the hello world program located in src/main.cpp with line

```
clang -Wall -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -c src/main.cpp -obuild/main.o
```

and the build suceeds

Then I link it with

```
clang -lc++ build/main.o -o qasix
```

and the linking suceeds too.
But when I run the program with

```
./qasix
```

I get the following error:

```
./qasix: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libc++.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE
```

I would like to know why this is occurring and also how to fix it.

I am on Xubuntu 13.10 if that's of any help.

PS: This problem popped up yesterday. Earlier other libc++ programs would compile fine.
This started when I did a debug build of a program with the -g flag and it compiled and ran fine, but all later programs complained about this symbol lookup failure. Please help.

Comment: http://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/01/17/building-clang-libcpp-ubuntu-linux/ these are the instructions i followed to build libc++ __only__. Clang I installed from llvm.orgs apt repo

Comment: Did you update your libc++ install between those events (the earlier versions succeeding, and everything after failing)?

Comment: BTW, `_ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE` unmangles to "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info"

Answer (score 0):

it appears that you need the support library "libc++abi". It provides things like low-level exception support, type_info support, etc.

For Ubuntu (as opposed to Xubuntu), it appears that you can get it here: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/saucy/universe/base/libc++abi-dev